# ERROR Error: NG0203: inject() after importing a Component declared in a custom angular library

Tags: angular, angular17

Hi I have created a custom angular library where I have implemented a simple CardComponent, this component uses MatRippleModule.

*card.component.ts*

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MatRippleModule } from '@angular/material/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'card',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [MatRippleModule],
  templateUrl: './card.component.html',
  styleUrl: './card.component.css'
})
export class CardComponent {}
```

*card.component.html*

```
<div matRipple>
    Click Me
</div>
```

*public-api.ts*

```
export * from './components/card/card.component';
```

I have built the library and installed into the AngularProject I want to use.

*example.component.ts*

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { CardComponent } from 'lib';

@Component({
    selector     : 'example',
    standalone   : true,
    templateUrl  : './example.component.html',
    imports      : [CardComponent],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class ExampleComponent {}
```

*example.component.html*

```
<div class="flex flex-col flex-auto min-w-0">
    <!-- Main -->
    <div class="flex-auto p-6 sm:p-10">
        <card></card>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see it's a simple example of how to install a and create a custom library but this time I have used Angular 17 for practice. But for some reason I ignore is not working, has to be something related of Angular 17 config, but what ? I have done this before in other angular versions and works properly.

Error:

```
src_app_modules_admin_example_example_routes_ts.js:2 ERROR Error: NG0203: inject() must be called from an injection context such as a constructor, a factory function, a field initializer, or a function used with `runInInjectionContext`. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0203
    at injectInjectorOnly (core.mjs:3824:15)
    at Module.ɵɵinject (core.mjs:3837:60)
    at Object.MatCommonModule_Factory [as useFactory] (core.mjs:83:103)
    at Object.factory (core.mjs:5338:38)
    at core.mjs:5239:43
    at runInInjectorProfilerContext (core.mjs:3644:9)
    at R3Injector.hydrate (core.mjs:5238:17)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:5106:33)
    at injectInjectorOnly (core.mjs:3831:40)
    at ɵɵinject (core.mjs:3837:60)
```

Note: The error be visible when I try to append "" in ExampleComponent template.

Comment: do share the github repo if its public for debugging!

Comment: I am facing the same issue, please let us know if you found a solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This typically happens when there's multiple copies of @angular/core present (cf [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/35586)).

Check you dependencies.

Comment: Could be more specific please ?, I don't understand the problem.

Comment: You library and your app have different @angular/core versions.

Comment: Have the same version:

Library Workspace dependencies:
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/cdk": "^17.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^17.2.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "^17.2.2",
    "@angular/core": "^17.2.2"

Library Project Dependencies:
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^17.2.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "^17.2.2",
    "@angular/core": "^17.2.2"

Angular App Dependencies:
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^17.2.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "^17.2.2",
    "@angular/core": "^17.2.2"

Comment: This does not help :(